# Flex custom component first item not read by JAWS

Tags: apache-flex, jaws-screen-reader

Flex application is being made accessibility compliant. When a custom component is made visible based on some condition, the first item (either text or formitem or textarea) inside the component is skipped by Jaws. It reads from the second item. On pressing UP arrow, the first item is then read.
Is there a way to make the first item accessible without need for pressing UP arrow?

Comment: Show the code that adds the component.

Comment: Just adding the pseudo code here. <mx:Application><com:CustomComp1 ../><com:CustomComp2 id="comp2" ../></mx:Application>  Here, the CustomComp2 will be made visible=false at first. Based on some condition satisfied in Application, CustomComp2 is made visible in script using comp2.visible=true. In this case, the first control inside the CustomComp2 is skipped by the Screen reader JAWS. Also pressing tab key also skips the first control when JAWS software is running. If I switch off JAWS, and then tab key press works just fine - does not skip the first control of the custom component. Any help?

Comment: Edit your question with the code...

Answer (score 0):

This is likely going to be related to focus management.

You're likely going to want to assign `componentId.setFocus()` to the first component in the current view when the view state changes.

You need to re-assess the focus when the state of your display changes.  If you post how you are managing display state I can suggest exactly how to trigger that via an event or in your custom state method.

Also, if that doesn't work, try this once your screen is ready / state changed :

```
focusManager.moveFocus(mx.events.FocusRequestDirection.TOP);
```

Comment: I tried setFocus(). setFocus did not help to move the focus of Screen reader.

Comment: Just to clarify, the setFocus() does set the focus into the field properly as expected, its just that the screen reader is still reading the wrong field?

Comment: Updated with another method that sets focus manager to absolute top.  That may do the trick.